# IntegerField validation bug

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

Hi I am trying to validate IntegerField  using Binder with this code:

```
binder.forField(number)
.withValidator(num -> num == null || (num >= 1 && num <= 999),
        getTranslation("number_must_be_between_1_and_999"))
    .bind(BusinessObject::getNumber, BusinessObject::setNumber);
```

The field is optional, but if entered, must be between 1 and 999.
It works fine until I try to enter a number greater than 2147483647 (the maximum Intger in Java).
For numbers greater than this, the validation passes without any warning, and the background business object gets a null value.
The field is in a dialog and what makes it even weirder is that the next time I open the same dialog, the IntegerField contains an invalid number entered even though null is written to the business object, Binder.readBean() stops working for that field.
How can I validate IntegerField correctly and avoid this bug and why is it not possible to limit the number of digits for an IntegerField? I am using Vaadin  23.3.0 .

Comment: You're probably facing this issue: https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/1035; workaround would be to use a TextField instead.